# Pump stays on even after digitalread is low

Tags: arduino, delay, arduino-ide

I am a beginner in Arduino programming. The objective of the script below is to turn on the pump on button press(d==0) wait for 8 seconds turn the pump off and send an SMS alert. When the button is released the pump stays off (emergency switch off).

Here I have managed to turn the pump on when the button is pressed and send a message. When the button is released the pump successfully turns off. However, the delay after 8 seconds turn off the pump doesn't really work which leaves me puzzled. Instead what happens is after 8 second delay the pump instantaneously jerks(toggles) then continues to stay on and send the message. I would appreciate any insight.

```
// Include the GSM library
#include <GSM.h>
#define PINNUMBER ""

// initialize the library instance
GSM gsmAccess;
GSM_SMS sms;

int pinout = 3;
int ledout = 13;
int d=1;
int a = 1;

void setup() {
  pinMode(4,INPUT); // Input Power
  pinMode(pinout , OUTPUT); // Motor Output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Sender");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while (notConnected) {
    if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) {
      notConnected = false;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
}

void loop() {
  d=digitalRead(4);
  // If digital state of pin 4 is zero start motor and power ON switch LED
  if(d==0){
  digitalWrite(pinout ,HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(ledout ,HIGH); 

  delay(8000); // This is the line that doesn't seem to work!
  digitalWrite(pinout ,LOW); // This is the line that doesn't seem to work!


  //for( a = 1; a < 2; a = a + 1 ){
  if (a<2){
  Serial.print("Enter a mobile number: ");
  char remoteNum[20] = "4xxxxxxx22"; 
  // sms text
  Serial.print("Now, enter SMS content: ");
  char txtMsg[200] = "Cow #57 SCC Abnormality Detected";
  //readSerial(txtMsg);
  Serial.println("SENDING");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Message:");
  Serial.println(txtMsg);

  // send the message
  sms.beginSMS(remoteNum);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS();
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");
  }
  a = a+1;
  Serial.println(a);
  }else{
  digitalWrite(pinout ,LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledout ,LOW);
  a=1;
  }
   //Serial.print(d);  // Monitor state of Pin 4 
}
```

Comment: If you add serial writes before and after the delay, what happens? Have you tried this already?

Comment: Hello helton, firstly thank you for taking the time to read my question. I just tried to add a serial.write line before and after the delay to check if the count is actually happening. It does print the two chars i put in aka the delay works well. However, Digital.write(pinout,low) is still instantaneous or it just desnt stay off.

Comment: Well, then try to isolate your problem. Instead of the pump, plug a Led into the correpondent pin. Go on removing "distracting" elements until you are sure your program logic is fine, then go on checking if the button works fine, the pump works fine, the serial works fine, etc. _one at a time_!